# Java, cant set text in textfields

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield

This is my code where is retrieves info from a database (code not shown). It is then meant to set the string text in a text field. However when I run the code no text appears in the text field. It prints out the values in the console when I use system.out

```
        int id_col = rs.getInt("ID");
        String id = Integer.toString(id_col);
        String surname = rs.getString("surname");
        String forename = rs.getString("forename");
        String dob = rs.getString("DOB");
        String address = rs.getString("address");
        String number = rs.getString("number");
        String gender = rs.getString("gender");
        String tutor = rs.getString("tutor");
        String email = rs.getString("email");


        idtext.setText(id);
        stext.setText(surname);
        ftext.setText(forename);
        gtext.setText(gender);
        dobtext.setText(dob);
        HM.setText(address);
        pe.setText(number);
        tg.setText(tutor);
        ea.setText(email);
```

Full Code:

```
package test;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JFrame;


public class Search extends javax.swing.JFrame {

Connection con;
Statement stmt;
ResultSet rs;

public Search() {
    initComponents();
    DoConnect();
}

public void DoConnect() {
    try {

        String host = "jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/Students";
        String uName = "admin1";
        String uPass = "admin1";
        con = DriverManager.getConnection(host, uName, uPass);

        stmt = con.createStatement();
        String sql = "SELECT * FROM student";
        rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM student");

        rs.next();
        int id_col = rs.getInt("ID");
        String id = Integer.toString(id_col);
        String surname = rs.getString("surname");
        String forename = rs.getString("forename");
        String dob = rs.getString("DOB");
        String address = rs.getString("address");
        String number = rs.getString("number");
        String gender = rs.getString("gender");
        String tutor = rs.getString("tutor");
        String email = rs.getString("email");


        idtext.setText(id);
        stext.setText(surname);
        ftext.setText(forename);
        gtext.setText(gender);
        dobtext.setText(dob);
        HM.setText(address);
        pe.setText(number);
        tg.setText(tutor);
        ea.setText(email);

        System.out.println( (id) + " " + (forename) + " " + (surname) + " " + (gender) );

    }

    catch ( SQLException err ) {
    System.out.println( err.getMessage( ) );
    }

}

/**
 * Creates new form Search
 */
{
    initComponents();
}

/**
 * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
 * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
 * regenerated by the Form Editor.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
private void initComponents() {

    jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jLabel3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    idtext = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    stext = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    ftext = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    gtext = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    jLabel4 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jLabel5 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jLabel6 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jLabel7 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jLabel8 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jLabel9 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    dobtext = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    HM = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    pe = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    tg = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    ea = new javax.swing.JTextField();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    jLabel1.setText("ID Number");

    jLabel2.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.SwingConstants.CENTER);
    jLabel2.setText("Surname");

    jLabel3.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.SwingConstants.CENTER);
    jLabel3.setText("Forename");

    idtext.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            idtextActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    ftext.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            ftextActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    gtext.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.JTextField.CENTER);
    gtext.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            gtextActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    jLabel4.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.SwingConstants.CENTER);
    jLabel4.setText("Date of Birth");

    jLabel5.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.SwingConstants.CENTER);
    jLabel5.setText("Home Address");

    jLabel6.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.SwingConstants.CENTER);
    jLabel6.setText("Phone Number");

    jLabel7.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.SwingConstants.CENTER);
    jLabel7.setText("Gender");

    jLabel8.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.SwingConstants.CENTER);
    jLabel8.setText("Tutor Group");

    jLabel9.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.SwingConstants.CENTER);
    jLabel9.setText("Email Address");

    dobtext.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.JTextField.CENTER);
    dobtext.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            dobtextActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    HM.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.JTextField.CENTER);

    pe.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.JTextField.CENTER);

    tg.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.JTextField.CENTER);

    ea.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.JTextField.CENTER);

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGap(47, 47, 47)
                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, false)
                        .addComponent(jLabel5, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                        .addComponent(jLabel4, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                        .addComponent(jLabel6, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                        .addComponent(jLabel7, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                        .addComponent(jLabel8, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                        .addComponent(jLabel9, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                        .addComponent(gtext)
                        .addComponent(dobtext)
                        .addComponent(HM)
                        .addComponent(pe)
                        .addComponent(tg)
                        .addComponent(ea)))
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addContainerGap(37, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                        .addComponent(jLabel1)
                        .addComponent(idtext, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 61, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                    .addGap(30, 30, 30)
                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                        .addComponent(stext)
                        .addComponent(jLabel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 100, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                    .addGap(34, 34, 34)
                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                        .addComponent(jLabel3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 100, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addComponent(ftext, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 100, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))))
            .addGap(38, 38, 38))
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(jLabel1)
                .addComponent(jLabel2)
                .addComponent(jLabel3))
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(ftext, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(stext, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addComponent(idtext, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
            .addGap(22, 22, 22)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(jLabel7)
                .addComponent(gtext, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(jLabel4)
                .addComponent(dobtext, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(jLabel5)
                .addComponent(HM, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(jLabel6)
                .addComponent(pe, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
            .addGap(10, 10, 10)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(jLabel8)
                .addComponent(tg, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(jLabel9)
                .addComponent(ea, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
            .addContainerGap(26, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );

    pack();
}// </editor-fold>                        

private void idtextActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                       
    // TODO add your handling code here:
}                                      

private void ftextActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                      
    // TODO add your handling code here:
}                                     

private void gtextActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                      
    // TODO add your handling code here:
}                                     

private void dobtextActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
    // TODO add your handling code here:
}                                       

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String args[]) {
    /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
    //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
    /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
     * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
     */
    try {
        for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Search.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Search.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Search.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Search.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    //</editor-fold>
    //</editor-fold>
    //</editor-fold>
    //</editor-fold>

    /* Create and display the form */
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new Search().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}

// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
private javax.swing.JTextField HM;
private javax.swing.JTextField dobtext;
private javax.swing.JTextField ea;
private javax.swing.JTextField ftext;
private javax.swing.JTextField gtext;
private javax.swing.JTextField idtext;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel3;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel4;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel5;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel6;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel7;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel8;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel9;
private javax.swing.JTextField pe;
private javax.swing.JTextField stext;
private javax.swing.JTextField tg;
// End of variables declaration
```

}

Comment: Can you try printing out those strings to the console when you run it to see if they are getting any values? I have a feeling the first part may be where the problem is coming from.

Comment: I'm saying to add System.out.println(*insert variable name here*) in between the code you just showed us and then tell us what prints out. If nothing prints out to your console, then its not a problem with text fields but instead with how you are getting the information from the database.

Comment: If you have a try/catch see if your code isn't going through a exception

Comment: You don't need to post your full code. It is even preferred to post [mcve]. Anyway without it all we can do is guess which isn't very effective while solving problem.

Comment: @JoshKopen Yes it does print out the values into the console. First thing I checked. Thank

Comment: @user2336714 how can i do that

Comment: @Pshemo that isnt the full code its the code i have a problem with

Comment: This code shows section where you are able to notice problem, but that doesn't mean that cause of problem is there. To get better help take your time and create proper [mcve] (you may be even able to find cause of problem by creating it).

Comment: The code that you post did not contains any error.

Comment: @Blasanka Thats my issue no error but not setting the text into the fields

Comment: I think problem with the `JTextField` instances

Comment: @Blasanka how can i fix that?

Comment: Only from this code I cannot give you a solution.

Comment: I can send you my code

Comment: Ok update the question.

Comment: updated the question @Blasanka

Comment: Uploaded old code. This is the newest code. Sorry @Blasanka

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you are invoke the `initComponents();` twise. One in constructor:

```
public Search() {
    initComponents();
    DoConnect();
}
```

And another one:

```
{
    initComponents();
}
```

Try removing last block.

Comment: Thank you @blasanka
Been trying to fix this for hours